# "Contextual Alternates" in a custom font is being used as default

Tags: ios, fonts

First of all, "Contextual Alternates" in fonts is something I've literally just found out about. Never have I heard this term before.

I have this font `VIC Infant Cursive GT-Regular v2.1` which looks like this in the app font book (note the strikethroughs). This is also how it appears in Xcode, the font-preview I mean.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmdpE.png]

Looking at the font we see normal characters:
[image]

And I opened the font in an app called "BirdFont" with hopes that I would be able to modify the font or something similar. No dice.

Looking at the available fonts in my app I can see the font family name and the font name. There is only one to choose from:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do?

The original font was in OTF, I've since converted it to TTF. Both display the same (i.e. wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a half-answer. But I finally found an app that could fix the font up (glyphsapp). I simply force-removed the characters in the font file itself.